# Unzip to internal storage not working completely

Tags: java, android

My file unzips one folder and one file but does not unzip the rest for some reason. How can I make it so it unzips all of the zip files contents?

```
public void unzip(String filepath, String filename, String unzip_path) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath + filename);
    Log.d("1st", filepath + filename);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    try {
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            String filename_temp = ze.getName();
            File fmd = new File(unzip_path + filename_temp);
            Log.d("2nd", unzip_path + filename_temp);
            if (!fmd.getParentFile().exists()) {
                fmd.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(unzip_path + filename_temp);

            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                fout.write(bytes);
                baos.reset();
            }

            fout.close();
            //}
        }
    } finally {
        zis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should catch the exception. in your try / finally

Comment: Put a zip file that gives problems somewhere on the internet. Then we can download it and test your code.

Comment: any zip file with multiple directories inside of it would be adequate to test the code.

Comment: I suggest that you catch and log an exception. I had the same problem unzipping on Android and found that it was caused by a spurious EOFException thrown by .getNextEntry() on what appear to be phantom entries. I never figured out why but I worked around it by catching EOFExceptions on getNextEntry and just skipping it.